# Download remote_file based on url generated from bash script

Tags: chef-infra

I have a scenario where I must download a file from a remote server, but the url for that file is generated via a bash script that I've included in `mycookbook/files/default/generate_url.sh'

I'm not sure how to go about crafting a recipe that executes the script from `files/default`, captures its stdout and uses the URL it spits out as the `source` attribute for the `remote_file` resource that will ultimately download the file.

Answer (score 1):

Either port the Bash script in to Ruby, do the download in Bash (probably via `curl`), or build a custom resource. The latter will be fairly complex so I recommend one of the first two.

Comment: Ended up creating my own resource. Was going to take your advice and create a Ruby version of the bash script, however `nokogiri` is b0rked on windows until they release `v1.8` https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1618

Comment: Unless you're working with huge documents, REXML in the stdlib is usually easier to deal with.